# php syntax error while creating an email in directadmin by api

Tags: php, directadmin

I'm trying to create an email into DirectAdmin by API
but my codes give back a syntax error on line 10 but i don't see anything wrong with that line.

```
<?php
  include('../da_api');
  $sock = new HTTPSocket;
  $sock->connect('mijndomein',2222);
  $sock->set_login('mijndomein','mijn 1337 ww');

  if(!empty($_POST['user']) && !empty($_POST['passwd']) is_numeric($_POST['quota'])) {
    $sock->query('/CMD_API_POP','domain=mijndomein&quota='.$_POST['quota'].'&action=create&user='.$_POST['user'].'&passwd='.$_POST['passwd'].'');
echo $sock->result;

    if(eregi('error=0', $sock->result)){
      echo '<p>Email adress is aan gemaakt<br />
      username:      '.$_POST['user'].'@mijndomein.nl<br />
      password:      '.$_POST['passwd'].'<br />
      Quota:         '.$_POST['quota'].'<br />
      POP3 server:    mail.mijndoemin.nl<br />
      SMTP server:    mail.mijndomein.nl*</p>';
    }
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed logical operator within `if` statement

```
if(!empty($_POST['user']) && !empty($_POST['passwd']) is_numeric($_POST['quota'])){
                                                     ^^^
```

should be

```
if(!empty($_POST['user']) && !empty($_POST['passwd']) && is_numeric($_POST['quota'])){
                                                      ^^^
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrong syntax for `if`. Missing operator `&&` or `||` before `is_numeric()`. It should be -

```
if(!empty($_POST['user']) && !empty($_POST['passwd']) && is_numeric($_POST['quota'])){
```

Answer (score 2):

You missed the logical operator at this line most probabaly you were indenting to write: `||` or `&&` operator there, before the `is_numeric($_POST['quota'])` in the if condition, it should be like

```
if(!empty($_POST['user']) && !empty($_POST['passwd']) && is_numeric($_POST['quota']))
```

or

```
if(!empty($_POST['user']) && !empty($_POST['passwd']) || is_numeric($_POST['quota']))
```